# How to properly post style to geoserver

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

I'm trying to post a new SLD style to geoserver and associate it to an existing layer, but keep getting errors. I'm doing the following:

```
curl -v -u XXXX:xxxxx -X POST "http://localhost/geoserver/rest/layers/landusemap_t11/styles" -H "content-type: application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml" -H "Content-Type: landusemap/collection/t11/defaultstyle/t11.sld" -d "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><StyleInfoPost>\t<name>landusemap_t11</name>\t<filename>t11.sld</filename></StyleInfoPost>"
```

I'm getting:

> Could not determine format. Try setting the Content-type header.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [GeoServer REST documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/styles.html) is quite clear as to [what format to use](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/styles.html#rest-api-styles-post-put). So assuming you are using SLD 1.0 you need to `POST` a `application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml` document to the `/styles` endpoint, optionally with a `name` parameter. So in your case something like:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -X POST -d @file.sld \
 -H "content-type: application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles.sld?name=mystylename
```

Once you have loaded the style you can [add it to a layer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/layers.html#layers-l-styles-format) by putting its name to the layer.

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -X PUT http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/layer.xml \
  -d '<layer><styles><style><name>mystylename</name></style></styles></layer>'
```

Comment: I ran your first command 
`curl -v -u admin:passw -X POST -d @t2.sld -H "content-type: application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles.sld?name=landusemap_t2`
and got:
`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 70; Element type "sld:StyledLayerDescriptorxmlns" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"`

Comment: is your SLD file correct? you may need to add `&raw=true` to the url if you have "odd" chars in it

Comment: I validate it in geoserver style editor and get no errors

Comment: how did you save it on disk? UTF-8 + BOM will break the parser with REST

Comment: I'm creating it with a python script.
The element it is complaining about goes like this in the file:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0.0">`

Comment: Only thing to do is turn logging up to geotools devel and look in the geoserver log file to get further details.

Comment: I got it. The problem was related to the XML not being well formed because spaces between element and attributes names were missing.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do this with Python and Requests library.

```
params = (
    ('name', 'style_name'),
)
with open(path_to_style.xml', 'r') as f:
        style = f.read()        
resp = session.post(url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles', params=params, data=style, auth=(geoserver_usrname, geoserver_pswrd), headers={'Content-type': 'application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml'})
```